# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED over SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, centos

I've been searching and haven't found a solution for this yet.

I have a LAMP server running Centos 5 and cPanel. I have converted the site from http to https. The site works just fine. However, periodically there are ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED errors on my PC only. This happens only over https and only periodically. Port 443 is open on the server.

FTP, Remote MySQL, SSH, and HTTPS connections are refused during that brief period. I've checked the server's firewall to allow my ip and unblock my ip. The ip is allowed and was never blocked.

We have other PCs connected to the same network with no issues during the brief period where only my connection is refused. I've cleared my cookies and cache with no luck. However, when I run a trace route, it stops at the first hop in our network.

Any suggestions with what I need to do or look at?
Do you think it is a server related issue?
Do you think it is an internal network related issue?
Could it be the issuer of the SSL cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into a full backlog queue. A Windows server will actively refuse a connection if the backlog queue is currently full. The defence is to increase the backlog or speed up the accept loop.

Comment: Thanks. I've increased it. I'll check to see if the problem continues.

Comment: This seems to have resolved the problem. I haven't had any issues since.